# Duvida sobre segurança na comunicação SSL de Sockets

Tags: java, socket

Gostaria de saber se essa comunicação entre os sockets, é seguro. Apartir desse código posso trocar informações com segurança?

Estou com dúvida também para entender como funciona a classe SSLContext (não está nesse código).

**Servidor**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.net.ServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;

public class MainClass extends Thread {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerSocketFactory ssf = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
    ServerSocket ss = ssf.createServerSocket(9096);

    while (true) {
      new SSLSimpleServer(ss.accept()).start();
    }
  }
  private Socket sock;
  public SSLSimpleServer(Socket s) {
    sock = s;
  }
  public void run() {
    try {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());

      String data = br.readLine();
      pw.println("What is she?");
      pw.close();
      sock.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      // Client disconnected
    }
  }
}
```

**Cliente**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SocketFactory sf = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    Socket s = sf.createSocket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("Who is Sylvia?");
    pw.println("Who is Sylvia?");
    pw.flush();
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
    s.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depende do que você chama de "segurança". Repare que SSL tem três princípios relacionados à segurança: confidencialidade, integridade, autenticidade.

- Qual a confiança que você tem no certificado que o servidor está enviando?
- O cliente aceita qualquer certificado? Como o cliente vai determinar se não tem um "man-in-the-middle"?
- Qual o criptograma usado? Qual o mínimo que você exige para chamar de "seguro"?

Para chamar uma conexão SSL de "segura", deve-se ter um certificado confiável e "não-forjável" (assegurado na medida do possível), com a comunicação acontecendo usando chaves seguras, usando um criptograma seguro o suficiente para não ser quebrado.

Exemplos:

- um certificado "self-signed" não garante que o servidor é quem ele diz que é. Logo, um man-in-the-middle pode forjar facilmente o certificado.
- uma comunicação feita via RC4 é considerada insegura, não importa a qualidade do seu certificado.

Agora, se a pergunta é se a comunicação entre o cliente e servidor está ocorrendo via SSL (sem importar a qualidade da comunicação em si), a resposta é sim. Você pode checar com o seguinte código:

```
Socket s = sf.createSocket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
SSLSession session = ((SSLSocket) s).getSession();
System.out.println("Criptograma: " + session.getCipherSuite());
System.out.println("Protocolo:" + session.getProtocol());
```

Comment: Hum sim, existem varias variaveis. Mas uma duvida essa comunicação do jeito que está, as mensagens estão sendo criptografadas então?